# Build a graph in popoto.js based on cypher query?

Tags: javascript, neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to initially present a graph using popoto.js viewer based on cypher query, using something like in the example:

```
MATCH (a1:Audit)-[r1:COVER|PERFORM|PRODUCED|ACHIEVE|DETERMINE|EVALUATE|ADDRESS|IDENTIFIED]-(n1)
WHERE n1.Definition = "requirements management" or 
n1.Definition =  "service level" or 
n1.Definition =  "monitoring" or 
n1.Definition =  "security" or 
n1.Definition =  "training"
RETURN a1, r1, n1
```